# Asp.Net Owin authorized request works in Incognito mode but not "normal" Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, cookies

I have an Asp.Net application that I can log into without a problem in Chrome, both in normal mode and Incognito. When I however do an API request it is only authorized in Incognito mode.

I then tried to do "Empty cache and hard reload", rebooted Chrome, cleared cookies, even restarted the computer etc but nothing works. I'm thinking if it could be some plugin but I tried disabling Ad-blocker and all the other plugins but I still get the same result. In Incognito everything works fine.

Local storage and session storage is empty and the only cookie present for Localhost is `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` in both non-incognito and incognito.

I then checked the request going to the server, this is from non-incognito:

```
GET /api/prospects/active HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3807
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ib450fjia5vizwpzxlnfuogd; XSRF-TOKEN=3hd4ZvxqpDU6sjttd22sjnxcrzCkptKajk3ml2maaf6oc8axj8N2P1QH6UzwPNeiKS4DhPYIhDVHzzwTaBb0-RF4ECjLZvPCUXqDEfrmaoIZ5rFOb2vubYL-PT4OGmyH0; XSRF-V=Zmq1iNyMWiHYOuEIYiKBGlEyW7pe1unHxGQN5K3zvn-30oHbX37JgMJTrlJMg0yCtLjfC2JJOiNOV9cO-ox6WIJgQR04cXZffeXzGfTF63E1; .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=RmjkiPr76LDahSXu-vOctxQY_TE0FT8nB-1ytaJ49_p3IYIntIO4fqu_CMuFalVYU9yls9FmGT8kC4L_Zb6fl12plkLfSlCuzVDkvwgi0QABCQ8oK9AgrN5wLx5Lk-OKMZ9LaxIpiDKuLuYFXX9F2LBE5524oEhk8fdUT-k8izwR5pJiBtPFV2PJ4U7ph77gNQRQNd3LMEKX2hYLIO4TjrfteVRClrAJYyVkP4uV9k_fWoHx-Lpx5aJiHIgM2naYqdyi9FmRYFOQRY1dScFhnz-PYYtfP_qkorjzjPLKDHfDQ06wzpuraB2J68bymbB4DG_d_Kr35d97O9WlGgLJo2qQV2HObQlGZ0qU3Dgmrib_ImmmFGcI3fwYWHV9WNV1kjUZ5DS9lIiZsAhqA8_eZbSKILmFw7L7vhMGNVKU6ptOeAyFqqRImY29nw2Fw5Rnrt3cy_Tw-pe229Ztvc7JRwfEF6bs7YqGWJTvGb1c3uE; UMB_UPDCHK=1; _ga=GA1.1.1065814793.1466085326; 3264e9011c=pe_data=|id=0b42d0758724f0295d9384687bcd6b0a; .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=Ol7PeRdke7-95-rLIAQY174l4UAly08mog8da0b7IHfAyHkcZTauLc7ZuGuynO5CTkuVokTuxrsPAwhUgeR9Ex9QpdcFeZV7COICBxBXSQADsbSCs1qf0daOG7LOId_ATup-pOiJcG1tr9JZ4biMdrPrsPE3Z3UITwWesD3UCovmmPMN7tk1cHKQ7XQO3M8tLRE_VWJX79R3aakNolFx2zKnUu15rsGSACcZzfANAGpZR59Ld0vr9378sSkIXrHOJWVgZyOloWlelQfKy1g5X5NZn2rIuBkS1gJrYAKf_4lR46BH8dR8pYbKAVYZb07xLAaiLBz7SkwMrc7nXIONIxnlKTKHBe43FSwu5mmAa5uRltd4Z7E4D_9J96OJd-hyFMA3n-F8SGL6diX6zxtSTjZfXmQmd-PJkzgg7FkuhPpb5nbCEMH6uI_JcU-ZZNbz4cAIbk0maLvLpUQKvkMz-txxNzgABgBUl753LaaHR0o
```

Result:

[image]

Incognito request:

```
GET /api/prospects/active HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3807
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=PxTseFnL3UPqv438ySa4f0Cb9mb-0ByyjjMDjTSCD9tSCmN4X0xYgIyMVVriHj1UJ8aogNe_ztHcEfr8pkE4xsMx2miVZ1Z50BGxBwY7sIz22fFQzDmC3-ASPMzYE6k9IFECpdqFfBLkb4rcSx_kd-flUb9hVLGa0zDC-qpypIEZJaYg2j50OfX9g9h0Ko4XXx9DJcDTE4qkPPmD52oMn2qLGSdSOFfLyi4tNE66vsh38Bi4DIxSB2wSHEBlWsE9LyZpwC8IN6C1B6R4XDuJaliWMZJCmoWLCr5X-YPWo-PQcrCiK_iCSp5ndJJJBsY65L2MiVDueShMTi4UeFwzk24kTUES_zhS0JSXEPrOyXGWV_1OAIAGkRObkN7YvD78jSairV547nfcPFzGTt6VPrUq6FkXGINV0AHa_5Vo03Ygjg3o6PgCB8kDrijYy_tAeA2rnmkCUsb8ZD6W-veCoujGKpHOTkuA1Ock1cczxTg
```

As you can see the non-incognito request has several more cookies even though the Chrome Developer Tools -> Application shows only one cookie.

[image]

What could be causing this?

Login controller:

```
private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager => HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

[HttpPost]
[Route("Login")]
public ActionResult Login(AuthenticationViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    User user = authenticationGateway.Authenticate(viewModel.Username, viewModel.Password);

    if (user == null)
    {
        logRepository.LogInformation("Login failed", $"Login attempt for user {viewModel.Username} from IP {Request.UserHostAddress} failed.", Guid.NewGuid());
        TempData["loginError"] = "Wrong username or password.";

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name, ClaimValueTypes.String),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email ?? string.Empty, ClaimValueTypes.Email),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.OtherPhone, user.Phone ?? string.Empty, ClaimValueTypes.String),
        new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.SalesId, user.UgId.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer)
    };

    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(claimsIdentity);

    logRepository.LogInformation("Login success", $"Login attempt for user {viewModel.Username} from IP {Request.UserHostAddress} succeeded.", Guid.NewGuid());

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
[Route("Logout")]
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    logRepository.LogInformation("Logout", $"Logged out user {User.Identity.Name}. Logout initiated from IP {Request.UserHostAddress}.", Guid.NewGuid());

    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();

    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

Startup.Auth:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Logout"),
            SlidingExpiration = true
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have tried to remove the cookies but it didn't help.
So I have tried to clear all the site data from the Chore Developer Console. It shows the specific port but helped for all the local web apps regarding of the port number
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some cookies were not removed properly. When I visited the api, `http://localhost:3807/api/prospects/active`,  directly in the browser Chrome Developer Tools showed all the cookies above. I don't know if it is a bug or not because the application and API are both running on localhost:3807. Chrome Developer Tools specifically says Cookies -> http://localhost:3807/ as well on both API and Web. When I removed the cookies manually everything started working after I logged in again.