# Web API 2 authorized not working as expected

Tags: cookies, authorize

I'm experiencing the same issue as the one mentioned here, for which there was no conclusive answer: [Asp.Net Owin authorized request works in Incognito mode but not "normal" Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288593/asp-net-owin-authorized-request-works-in-incognito-mode-but-not-normal-chrome/40718174#40718174)

I am unable to comment on that question as I do not have the reputation to allow but was going to ask whether it is something to do with the fact that my project includes both Web Forms and Web API and there is a conflict going on with the authorization cookie.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone else with the same issue:

It was indeed due to forms authentication being enabled at the same time as OWIN bearer tokens.

If you are logged in via forms authentication, then try to call a web api end-point in the same browser, it uses the cookie information which gets recognized by Web Api authorization.

In incognito, there is no such cookie so behaves as expected.